# $H=E-k \alpha \alpha ^T$ is orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $\alpha$ is n-dim vector, $\alpha ^T\alpha =1$. Solve for $k$ such that $H=E-k \alpha  \alpha ^T$ is orthogonal matrix.

I guess that $\alpha  \alpha ^T$ is a identity matrix, then k is $0$ or $2$.

$$\det (H)=\det \left(E-k \alpha  \alpha ^T\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

$\alpha\alpha^T$ is not necessarily identity matrix. The solution is directly followed by the definition of orthogonal matrix
$$\begin{align}E=&H^TH\\
=&(E-k\alpha\alpha^T)^T(E-k\alpha\alpha^T)\\
=&(E-k\alpha\alpha^T)(E-k\alpha\alpha^T)\\
=&E-2k\alpha\alpha^T+k^2\alpha(\alpha^T\alpha)\alpha^T\\
=&E-2k\alpha\alpha^T+k^2\alpha\alpha^T\end{align}$$
which requires $k=0,2$

Comment: Be careful: for this you need $\alpha$ a unit vector, but the fix is easy enough.

Comment: Of course, but $\alpha$ is a unit vector is given by OP

Answer (score 1):

The other users have given their answers with rigourous proofs, so I will discuss only *your* answer attempt.

Your guess is right but your reasoning is wrong. $\alpha\alpha^T$ has only rank 1, so it can *never* be the identity matrix unless $n=1$. You tried to deduce that $k=0,2$ using determinant. This can be justified by the formula $\det(E+k\alpha\alpha^T)=1+k\alpha^T\alpha$ for any vector $\alpha$ and any scalar $k$.